# Передача аргументов в subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Как передать команду с |

```
import subprocess

command_listen = ('ps','-A','|','grep','message')
print (command_listen)
process = subprocess.Popen(command_listen, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
data = process.communicate(timeout=10)
print(data[0].decode('utf-8'))
```

таким образом пишет error: garbage option
если выполнять ps -A то все впорядке но вот передать | никак не могу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А [попробуйте](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20434281/5909792) так:

```
command_listen = '''ps -A | grep message'''
print(command_listen)
process = subprocess.Popen(command_listen, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
print(process.communicate())
```

или так:

```
sub_process = subprocess.Popen(['ps','-A'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process = subprocess.Popen(['grep','message'], stdin=sub_process.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(process.communicate())
```

Comment: `communicate()` не забыли?

Comment: @eri, угу, все-таки для полноты картины, лучше добавить :)

Answer (score 0):

Но для таких простых команд проще ж использовать

```
import os
print(os.popen('ps -A | grep message').read())
```

Comment: А самое правильное (по-питоновски) использовать соответствующие библиотеки.

Comment: А что за соответствующие библиотеки?